# 400 response from GAE Cloud Endpoints

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm trying the following api call to my GAE Cloud Endpoint:

```
gapi.client.myapp.foo.update({
  "value": "foobar",
  "key": "keyvaluefromlistoperation"
}).execute(function(resp) {
  console.log(resp);
});
```

Which responds with the following:

```
[
 {
  "error": {
   "code": 400,
   "message": "Bad Request",
   "data": [
    {
     "domain": "usageLimits",
     "reason": "keyInvalid",
     "message": "Bad Request"
    }
   ]
  },
  "id": "gapiRpc"
 }
]
```

Note, prior to this call I have authenticated, inserted several foo objects, then call list to have them returned to the client.  The api's explorer update call works fine and running the jQuery snippet below works fine as well.  Any suggestions?  Or am I just in experimental bug land.

```
var token = gapi.auth.getToken();
$.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  beforeSend: function (request) {
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
    request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", token.token_type+" "+token.access_token);
  },
  url: "https://myappid.appspot.com/_ah/api/myapp/v1/foo/update",
  data:JSON.stringify({
     "value": "foobar",
     "key": "keyvaluefromlistoperation"
  }),
  processData: false,
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
  },
  failure: function(msg) {
     console.log(msg);
  }
});
```

Here is the Java code:

```
@Api(
    name = "myapp",
    description = "This is the myapp rest interface",
    scopes = {"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"},
    version = "v1",
    clientIds = {Ids.WEB_CLIENT_ID}
)
public class FooV1 {

    private static PersistenceManager getPersistenceManager() {
        return PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    }

    @ApiMethod(
            name = "foo.update", 
            httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST
    )
    public Foo update(Foo foo, User user) throws OAuthRequestException, IOException, UnauthorizedUpdateException {
        PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();

        if (user != null) {
            try {
                Foo f = pm.getObjectById(Foo.class, foo.getId());
                if ( Security.isUpdateAuthorized(f, user) ) {
                    if( foo.getValue() != null ) f.setValue(foo.getValue());
                } else {
                    throw new UnauthorizedUpdateException("");
                }
            } finally {
                pm.close();
            }
        } else {
            throw new OAuthRequestException("Invalid user.");
        }

        return foo;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this error consistently occurring or intermittent?

Comment: occurring consistently for almost two days now.

Comment: On every request to `gapi.client.myapp.foo.update`? If not, what percentage?

Comment: Every update using the client package 'gapi.client.myapp.foo.update' fails. 100%

Comment: Interesting. Do you have a deployed application? Python or Java app?

Comment: Its deployed to app engine.  Running at .appspot.com.  And its java.

Comment: Can you post the code for your Endpoint class?

Comment: Sure, added to post above.

Comment: Can you rename the key property of Foo to something else (like myKey) as a test and try again? If that works, I can provide an answer about what's happening.

Comment: Will have to give it a try in the morning.  GAE is just spinning on deployment right now (perhaps I'm making it angry...).

Comment: Ok, I have the api updating again.  This is my response now: [
 {
  "error": {
   "code": -32099,
   "message": "java.lang.NullPointerException",
   "data": [
    {
     "domain": "global",
     "reason": "backendError",
     "message": "java.lang.NullPointerException"
    }
   ]
  },
  "id": "gapiRpc"
 }
]  Looks like it's still saving and using 'key' in the request, not 'mykey'

Comment: Can you update your code in the question to reflect the current state? What you have now sounds like a different issue.

Comment: I was finally able to work around all of my problems by 1) changing the uid parameter 'key' to 'id' and then 2) changing the version number.  If I only did (1) my deploy would fail.  I have been able to work just fine on the new version (v2) with the updated parameter name (id).

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem. Apparently you can't use "key" as a field once you deploy to GAE. Locally it worked fine.